# Newrelic Apache Httpd Plugin on Centos

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am trying to configure Httpd Plugin

I am getting 403 error , any suggestions how to fix this issue

```
INFO       2014-12-16 19:52:14,885 14962  MainProcess     MainThread newrelic_plugin_agent.agent                   __init__                  L55    : Agent v1.3.0 initialized, Linux-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5 (CentOS 6.5 Final) CPython v2.6.6
INFO       2014-12-16 19:52:14,886 14962  MainProcess     MainThread helper.controller                             run                       L251   : newrelic-plugin-agent v2.4.1 started
INFO       2014-12-16 19:52:14,886 14962  MainProcess     MainThread newrelic_plugin_agent.agent                   start_plugin_polling      L263   : Enabling plugin: apache_httpd
ERROR      2014-12-16 19:52:19,450 14962  MainProcess     MainThread newrelic_plugin_agent.plugins.base            http_get                  L354   : Error response from   localhost:80/server-status?auto (403): 

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
    <p>You don't have permission to access /server-status
    on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
    </body></html>

ERROR      2014-12-16 19:52:19,451 14962  MainProcess     MainThread newrelic_plugin_agent.plugins.apache_httpd    error_message             L61    : Could not match any of the stats, please make ensure Apache HTTPd is configured correctly. If you report this as a bug, please include the full output of the status page from localhost:80/server-status?auto in your ticket
WARNING    2014-12-16 19:52:19,451 14962  MainProcess     MainThread newrelic_plugin_agent.agent                   send_components           L217   : No metrics to send to NewRelic this interval
INFO       2014-12-16 19:52:19,451 14962  MainProcess     MainThread newrelic_plugin_agent.agent                   process                   L133   : Stats processed in 4.57 seconds, next wake in 55 seconds
```

Comment: What permissions have you set for `/server-status`?

Comment: <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 
</Location>   : @JeremiahWinsley

Comment: You might try adding the local ip to an Allow directive. Apache may not be resolving localhost to the loopback interface properly.

Comment: No still same error even after modifying with ip address : @JeremiahWinsley

Comment: What do you get with `wget http://localhost/server-status`?

Comment: --2014-12-16 20:40:22--  http://localhost/server-status
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-12-16 20:40:22 ERROR 403: Forbidden. : @JeremiahWinsley

Comment: Check your other apache config files and make sure you aren't overriding `/server-status` anywhere. Also make sure you restart/reload after each change. Using the same configuration, I get no error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to the end of **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** if you prefer it in a separate file as I do, then create a file such as **/etc/httpd/conf.d/status.conf** and put them in there.

```
ExtendedStatus On

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

This is saying that you want to expose the server status on the /server-status uri. It also will only allow connections from 127.0.0.1, which means you are only allowing to server this page from requests made directly from the server.

Once you've made the change, make sure you run:

```
service httpd restart
```

you can then validate that it's working by doing any of the following depending on your system configuration.

```
lynx --dump http://127.0.0.1/server-status
curl -vs http://127.0.0.1/server-status
wget -qO- http://127.0.0.1/server-status
```